# Applying a function to dataframe columns with multiple conditional statements

Tags: python-3.x, function, pandas, multiple-columns, apply

let's say I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#
a = ['a','b']*6
b = ['c','c','d','d']*3
c = np.linspace(1,12,12)
d = np.linspace(2,13,12)
e = np.linspace(3,14,12)
f = np.linspace(4,15,12)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': a, 'B': b, 'C': c, 'D': d, 'E': e, 'F': f})
df2 = df1.drop(columns=['A','B'])
```

which gives

```
In [2]: df1
Out[2]:
    A  B     C     D     E     F
0   a  c   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
1   b  c   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0
2   a  d   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0
3   b  d   4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0
4   a  c   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0
5   b  c   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0
6   a  d   7.0   8.0   9.0  10.0
7   b  d   8.0   9.0  10.0  11.0
8   a  c   9.0  10.0  11.0  12.0
9   b  c  10.0  11.0  12.0  13.0
10  a  d  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0
11  b  d  12.0  13.0  14.0  15.0
```

What I'm trying to do is to apply a function to columns C to E based on

- the values in A and B
- how the values in C to E compare to D

I got it to work with a for loop buy it's way too slow (the dataframe is huge in reality)

Here's what I've done instead to speed up things

```
f1 = lambda x: x - df1['D'] if x > df1['D'] else df1['D'] - x
f2 = lambda x: x + df1['D'] if x > df1['D'] else df1['D'] + x + 10
f3 = lambda x: x - df1['D'] if x > df1['D'] else df1['D'] - x
f4 = lambda x: x + df1['D'] if x > df1['D'] else df1['D'] + x + 5

df1.loc[(df1['A'] == 'a') & (df1['B'] == 'c'), 'C':'E'] = df2.apply(f1)
df1.loc[(df1['A'] == 'a') & (df1['B'] == 'd'), 'C':'E'] = df2.apply(f2)
df1.loc[(df1['A'] == 'b') & (df1['B'] == 'c'), 'C':'E'] = df2.apply(f3)
df1.loc[(df1['A'] == 'b') & (df1['B'] == 'd'), 'C':'E'] = df2.apply(f4)
```

This way I get the ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous') with the problem being the "if" in the lambdas definition.

I then tried the following

```
f1 = lambda x: x - df1['D']
f2 = lambda x: x + df1['D']
f3 = lambda x: x - df1['D']
f4 = lambda x: x + df1['D'] 

np.where(df1.loc[(df1['A'] == 'a') & (df1['B'] == 'c'), 'C':'E'] > df1.loc[(df1['A'] == 'a') & (df1['B'] == 'c'), 'D'], df2.apply(f1), df2.apply(f2))
```

to somehow pass the "if" to np.where but I get the ValueError: ('operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,6) (12,4) (12,4)').

Any help much appreciated as I'm running out of ideas!

Thanks

Comment: Can you help me understand at a high level, what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Basically I want to apply the function "f1" to columns C to E when columns A and B have values "a" and "c" respectively. The function "f1" in turn is conditional to whether the values in C to E are greater than the values in D, it returns two different calculations depending on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? Inspired by `np.select` (but can't make that work directly!)

```
conditions = [
    (df1['A'] == 'a') & (df1['B'] == 'c'), 
    (df1['A'] == 'a') & (df1['B'] == 'd'), 
    (df1['A'] == 'b') & (df1['B'] == 'c'), 
    (df1['A'] == 'b') & (df1['B'] == 'd')
]

choices = [
    np.abs(df2.subtract(df2['D'], axis=0)),
    (df2.add(df2['D'], axis=0) + df2.gt(df2['D'], axis=0) * 10),
    np.abs(df2.subtract(df2['D'], axis=0)),
    (df2.add(df2['D'], axis=0) + df2.gt(df2['D'], axis=0) * 5)
]

new_dfs = []
for i in range(len(conditions)):
    c = choices[i][conditions[i]]
    new_dfs.append(c)

res = pd.concat(new_dfs).sort_index()
print(res)
```

Which gives

```
       C     D     E     F
0    1.0   0.0   1.0   2.0
1    1.0   0.0   1.0   2.0
2    7.0   8.0  19.0  20.0
3    9.0  10.0  16.0  17.0
4    1.0   0.0   1.0   2.0
5    1.0   0.0   1.0   2.0
6   15.0  16.0  27.0  28.0
7   17.0  18.0  24.0  25.0
8    1.0   0.0   1.0   2.0
9    1.0   0.0   1.0   2.0
10  23.0  24.0  35.0  36.0
11  25.0  26.0  32.0  33.0
```

Can you give a sample of what you expect the output dataframe to be in your example, if this isn't correct?

Comment: It did work with a slight modification on the choices to do what the expression inthe function says and to apply it only to selected columns C to E`choices = [
    np.abs(df2.loc[:,'C':'E'].subtract(df2['D'], axis=0)),
    (df2.loc[:,'C':'E'].add(df2['D'], axis=0) + df2.loc[:,'C':'E'].le(df2['D'], axis=0) * 10),
    np.abs(df2.loc[:,'C':'E'].subtract(df2['D'], axis=0)),
    (df2.loc[:,'C':'E'].add(df2['D'], axis=0) + df2.loc[:,'C':'E'].le(df2['D'], axis=0) * 5)
]`

Comment: You are better to modify df2 to only include the columns you are interested in, rather than doing it every time. so just set `df2 = df2.loc[:, 'C':'E']`, then use as I have. That way don't need to duplicate that selection each time. If my answer is what you were answer, can you upvote/accept it?

Comment: Yes good point actually on narrowing down the columns. Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying what you wanna do here is is a 2 liner for f1 (NB abs instead of if-else):

```
inds_Aa_Bc=df1[(df1["A"]=="a")& (df1["B"]=="c")].index
df1.loc[inds_Aa_Bc,"C"]=abs(df1.loc[inds_Aa_Bc,"C"]-df1.loc[inds_Aa_Bc,"D"])
```

Line1 get the indexes of the rows satisfying what you want

Line2 do the f1 operation on column "C"

Not sure what you mean by "C" to "E" but in cae just repeat line2 for these columns

For f2 you need also 2 lines but a bit messier:

```
inds_Aa_Bd=df1[(df1["A"]=="a")& (df1["B"]=="d")].index

df1.loc[inds_Aa_Bd,"C"]=np.where(df1.loc[inds_Aa_Bd,"C"]<=df1.loc[inds_Aa_Bd,"D"],df1.loc[inds_Aa_Bd,"C"]+df1.loc[inds_Aa_Bd,"D"]+10,df1.loc[inds_Aa_Bd,"C"]+df1.loc[inds_Aa_Bd,"D"])
```

Line1 again get the indexes of wanted rows

Line2 use np.where (condition, value if condition=True, value if contition==False)

f3 and f4 are very similar to f1 and f2:

```
#f3
inds_Ab_Bc=df1[(df1["A"]=="b")& (df1["B"]=="c")].index
df1.loc[inds_Ab_Bc,"C"]=abs(df1.loc[inds_Ab_Bc,"C"]-df1.loc[inds_Ab_Bc,"D"])

#f4
inds_Ab_Bd=df1[(df1["A"]=="b")& (df1["B"]=="d")].index

df1.loc[inds_Ab_Bd,"C"]=np.where(df1.loc[inds_Ab_Bd,"C"]<=df1.loc[inds_Ab_Bd,"D"],df1.loc[inds_Ab_Bd,"C"]+df1.loc[inds_Ab_Bd,"D"]+5,df1.loc[inds_Ab_Bd,"C"]+df1.loc[inds_Ab_Bd,"D"])
```

Running all this returns:

```
df1
    A  B     C     D     E     F
0   a  c   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
1   b  c   1.0   3.0   4.0   5.0
2   a  d  17.0   4.0   5.0   6.0
3   b  d  14.0   5.0   6.0   7.0
4   a  c   1.0   6.0   7.0   8.0
5   b  c   1.0   7.0   8.0   9.0
6   a  d  25.0   8.0   9.0  10.0
7   b  d  22.0   9.0  10.0  11.0
8   a  c   1.0  10.0  11.0  12.0
9   b  c   1.0  11.0  12.0  13.0
10  a  d  33.0  12.0  13.0  14.0
11  b  d  30.0  13.0  14.0  15.0
```

Comment: It did work but it applies the calculation to C only. I tried to modify it with the foloowng`inds_Aa_Bc=df1[(df1["A"]=="a")& (df1["B"]=="c")].index
df1.loc[inds_Aa_Bc,'C':'E']=abs(df1.loc[inds_Aa_Bc,'C':'E']-df1.loc[inds_Aa_Bc,"D"])` to apply it to Columns from C to E but I  got this error "ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray"

Comment: I am sure there is a smarter way @AleVis but the only way I found to do it is to call it 3 times for each f-function, once for "C", once for "D" and once for "E"; that is what I meant with _Not sure what you mean by "C" to "E" but in cae just repeat line2 for these columns_ in my reply

Comment: Yes I'll have a good think at it as the idea behind is brilliant. I tried `df1.loc[inds_Aa_Bc,'C':]` or `df1.loc[inds_Aa_Bc,['C','D','E']]` they return NaN instead. Thanks for your invaluable help

Comment: You are welcome, so you can accept my answer till someone comes with a better solution ;). Btw you can pack it all into a loop over the columns:
define the indices `inds_XX=YY` then `cols=["C",D","E"]`then loop : `for col in cols: df1.loc[inds_Aa_Bc,"C"]=abs(..)
df1.loc[inds_Aa_Bd,col]=np.where(...)  
...`